# Which directory is returned by `cat <(-)` in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I was playing around with concatenation in a pipe and ran:

```
cat <(-)
```

What is `zsh` doing under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean about it returning a directory. In terms of what zsh does here, `echo <(-)` will give you a clue. It will likely print something like `/dev/fd/12` or perhaps the name of a temporary file depending on your system.

`<( ... )` is a zsh construction. Zsh creates a subshell and runs the command in the subshell with the commands stdout directed to a pipe. It then substitutes the other end of the pipe using `/dev/fd` or `/proc/self/fd` depending on your operating system. The `-` command, actually a precommand modifier, does nothing alone. So after it finishes doing nothing it ends and with it goes its end of the pipe. `cat` reads an end-of-file and exits in turn. Compare what happens with something like `cat <(echo hi)`.

The similar form `=( ... )` forces the use of a temporary file. This is useful if you have a command like `diff` that needs to be able to seek to random positions in the file. Finally, there is `>( ... )` which will output to a command, a bit like a pipe.

Comment: Yes, `echo <(-)` will print `/proc/self/fd/11`, on my system this returns $OLDPWD. I was wondering if that was by accident, or if it could be expected. I understand as far as how you explained, but not (1) why the thing returned is not some temporary non-existing file handle, nor (2) the consistency of getting $OLDPWD.

Comment: I'd guess you've got `-` aliased to something like `popd` or `cd -`. They print the new directory unless the `pushd_silent` option is set. But because the command in `<( ... )` is run in a subshell, the change of directory won't take effect in the parent directory. I take it you're using a plugin framework like oh-my-zsh if you've got aliases you didn't know were there.

Comment: Ah, that's it! `alias` in zsh shows that `-` is indeed a shorthand for `cd -`, probably indeed introduced by a (default) plugin in `oh-my-zsh`.

Answer (score 1):

`-` is a precommand modifier; according to `man zsh`:

```
   -      The  command  is  executed  with  a `-' prepended to its argv[0]
          string.
```

In the expression `cat <(-)`, this should amount to a null command (with no output that automatically succeeds) running as if it were named `-`. I am not sure you how are getting any output related to the old working directory, though. `cd -` would print the *new* working directory`, but`-`doesn't trigger a directory change even with`auto_cd`enabled (and`auto_cd`shouldn't apply inside a process substitution anyway, since`SHIN_STDIN` is not set).

(Apologies; this might be more suitable as a comment on the question, rather than an answer.)